# Autolayout iphone 5 error app store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I release my app (Geo Halcon, Geo Falcon in english) in the App Store some days ago.

I prepare my storyboard for autolayout in iPhone 5, but now, I download my app in my iPhone 5 and it don't show the full height.

If I install the app from my xcode I see the app in full screen, but if I download it from App Store have a 3.5 inch size.

I think the problem is in location because I have english, italian and spanish with it's default file for iPhone 5, but in XCode there are a warning saying that there are not default image for iPhone 5.

What is happening? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was very simple.

When I configure the location the default image disappear from initial configuration. I just add it again and solve the problem.

It seems that Apple check the configuration of default file for iPhone 5 to decide if the app support iPhone 5 layout or not.

THanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Warning : "Code there are a warning saying that there are not default image for iPhone 5" clearly says the problem. You have not added iPhone 5 default screen.

Add one image with this name "Default-568h@2x.png. For more information take a look in apple's guide.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12

Comment: But in each location folder I have this image, if apple use this image for detect an iPhone 5 compatible app is a great error for apps with multi language. 

The problem is that I don't know how to probe it, because this only happens in the app store, when I install the app with xcode it works.

Comment: What great error? Apple using this way to support the iPhone 5 full screen layout.

Comment: My directory is like:

-myApp
  .
  .
  .-> es
      .-> default-568h@2x.png
  .-> en
      .-> default-568h@2x.png

The problem is the default file must be located because my app name is different for each region